# Juniper SRX 340 route lookup failed

Tags: routing, firewall, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, asymmetric-routing

I've a strange issue on my Juniper; I've a policy to allow all traffic to a specific address behind it and, in effect, the policy works correctly.
All the traffic I send reach the destination, except 1 single source; after a little debug (enabling the packet filter), I found this error:

```
Nov 26 14:55:32 14:55:32.062525:CID-1:RT:  route lookup failed: dest-ip AA.BB.CC.DD orig ifp .local..0 output_ifp reth1.0 fto 0x4b01f430 orig-zone 2 out-zone 6 vsd 0
Nov 26 14:55:32 14:55:32.062606:CID-1:RT:  readjust timeout to 6 s

Nov 26 14:55:32 14:55:32.062606:CID-1:RT:  packet dropped,   pak dropped since re-route failed
```

Searching around in literature I found a lot of examples, but all related to VPN, VR or asymmetric routing; nothing of them are my case: the destination address is directly connected, I don't use any kind of VR and I don't have any VPN related to these addresses. The show route command shows the correct route for both addresses (external interface for source IP and internal for destination IP).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Just to make sure we know what you mean, are you saying that every source host you have in zone 2 is able to reach the same destination host in zone 6, except for one specific host in zone 2?

Comment: Can you post a full sanitized config of the SRX?

Comment: Hi Jesse. Yes, what you said is correct (every source host I have in zone 2 is able to reach the same destination host in zone 6, except for one specific host in zone 2). I try to sanitaze the conf! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a debug session with Juniper support, we found the problem: it's a bug related to the 15.1X49-D70.3 firmware version.
Basically the flow matched self-traffic-policy and SRX dropped packet because it not recognized the address as local.

Thanks to all,
Gianluca